# Magento 2: Module Manager error

Tags: magento2, third-party-module

I’m trying to enable a module in my `Magento 2.2.2.` But as in the readiness check, PHP Settings Check is giving me the following error.

[image]

so, I checked my PHP Memory Limit and here the screenshot

[image]

I also tried installing through SSH but what it only does it give me random glitches.

Comment: restart your webserver and try to install again

Comment: what command should i use?My server is CentOs.

Answer (score 0):

Find the php.ini file in your system

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

and try to change the memory limit in Both php.ini file

restart your webserver:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: im not having a root access to the server. im on a shared server

Comment: also the customer support wont restart the server